# Foreign key associated with column could not find

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i am trying to create the relationship between the following two tables. but the code is raising the error.

```
class TeacherModel(db.Model):
    __Tablename__="Teacher"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True,nullable=False)
    Course_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("Courses.id"),nullable=True)

    Course=db.relationship("CourseModel", back_populates="teacher")


class TeacherUserModel(db.Model):
    __Tablename__="TeacherUsers"

    id= db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False, unique=True)
    password=db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False, unique=True)
    Teacher_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Teacher.id"),unique=True, nullable=False)
```

raise exc.NoReferencedTableError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'teacher_user_model.Teacher_id' could not find table 'Teacher' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo, it should be `__tablename__` lowercase. I recommend to always use lowercase and snake_case, except for class names where its ok to use CapWords convention as recommended by PEP-8.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).